# Calculating Cartesian product in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples, combinations

There are 2 same arrays, A=np.array(['A','B','C']),B=np.array(['A','B','C']), I calculated the Cartesian product of A and B:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
b=product(A,B)
```

the result of b is

```
[('A','A'),('A','B'),('A','C'),('B','A'),('B','B'),('B','C'),('C','A'),('C','B'),('C','C)]
```

In my project, the meaning of ('A','B') is the same as ('B','A'), How could I drop the duplications of b? I want to make b only reserve ('A','B'), ('A','C'), ('B','C'). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) on a single array:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
list(combinations_with_replacement(A, r=2))
```

output:

```
[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'C')]
```

##### excluding self combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations
list(combinations(A, r=2))
```

output:

```
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]
```

Comment: How could I drop ('A','A'), ('B','B'), ('C','C') in this list?

Comment: by using `combinations`